# Why must be the Merkle Tree a full binary?

Tags: merkle-tree

Bitcoin uses a Merkle tree with hash functions. I mean I do not get it why there must be a full binary tree? A complete could also be possible?

Comment: Bitcoin [messed up](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2106/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-different-hash-functions-for-the-leaves-and-interna) their merkle trees . I guess requiring a power-of-two as leaves is their workaround for this flaw.

Comment: Related: [\[Full Disclosure\] CVE-2012-2459 (block merkle calculation exploit)](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=102395.0) on bitcointalk.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: The second link is interesting, but I don't see what the first link has to do with the question?

Comment: @Murch It's about how you to design a proper merkle tree that doesn't suffer from ambiguities between different length inputs. Such a merkle tree won't need silly restrictions like a power-of-two number of leaves. But bitcoin didn't use leaf-tagging (or one of the alternative safe constructions) which led to problems.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Bitcoin doesn't require a full binary tree, it only requires a complete binary tree. I thought you were saying that you didn't understand why a binary tree was chosen over more children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bitcoin does work with full or complete binary trees.** For complete trees, leaves without a partner are simply hashed with themselves instead. The attack that [CodesInChaos](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50762/why-must-be-the-merkle-tree-a-full-binary#comment58878_50762) links was solved by checking that every transaction is unique which is required for valid blocks anyway.

[image]

<sup>Image from Bitcoin Developer Guide</sup>